# 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'artists'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 select * from `appointments` 
 inner join `artists` 
 on `appointments`.`artist_id` = `artists`.`id` 
 inner join `artists` 
 on `appointments`.`client_id` = `artists`.`id`
```

I can't figure out this, I need two joins on the same table with different params with other table's unique id.

Comment: USe two different table aliases for artists table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need table aliases:

```
select *
from appointments ap inner join
     artists aa
     on ap.artist_id = aa.id inner join
     artists ac
     on ap.client_id = ac.id;
```